# mouse movement over canvas stops the timer

Tags: vb.net, performance, canvas, geometry, mouse

Is there another method other than freeze that will prevent the computer from monitoring mouse position relative to the geometry objects?

I have two panels containing buttons and text boxes on each side of the WPF window. Between the two panels is a canvas. A timer is running 10x per second and displaying numbers 1 to 10 in a text box in the side panel. The canvas has a child which is a temporary canvas I created containing many lines. The temporary canvas is loaded with a geometry group (the many lines) via a path and then is added to the main canvas as a child. 
The problem is...
When my mouse moves around the side panels the timer keeps good time and the numbers 1 to 10 plot perfectly in the text box. Zooming in and out is also very fast. When I move the mouse over the canvas the numbers in the text box slow down and even stop when the mouse moves quickly over the canvas.
The problem is isolated to the geometry group. When I comment that out the problem goes away.

I have tried Freezing the geometry group and brushes. NO change in the timer slow down.
I have deleted my canvas_mouse move event. NO change in timer slow down.
I have made the geometry group smaller (less lines). Better speed in timer but still slow.

Is there another method other than freeze that will prevent the computer from monitoring mouse position relative to the geometry objects?

My program is very large so I am posting just the temporary canvas section below.

```
       TempCanvas.Children.Clear()


        Dim myPathPXF As Path = New Path
        myPathPXF.Stroke = Brushes.Black
        myPathPXF.StrokeThickness = 10
        myPathPXF.Data = myGeometryGroupPXF
        TempCanvas.Children.Add(myPathPXF)   'mouse movement over canvas stops program with this line

        'created in world coordinates and render to screen coordinates
        TempCanvas.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup

    'show on plan view canvas
    PlanViewCanvas.Children.Clear()
    PlanViewCanvas.Children.Add(TempCanvas)
```

I searched online for days and could not find anyone with the same problem.  Thank you for any help in advance.

The geometryGroup has about 1,000 lines.

Just discovered that when I open a dialog the timer runs at the proper rate because the mouse is no longer being tracked I assume.

EDIT:
I was using Visual Studio 2019. I just ran my code through Visual Studio 2015 and the problem went away.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code seems VBasic. If so, please edit your question and add the proper tag; you will get more responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not seems to be related to the geometry group. When I switched from using Visual Studio 2019 to using Visual Studio 2015 the problem went away.

Comment: That's great! It's possible your code was built for older versions of Visual Studio, I had this problem in the past too. I loaded my project created with VS 2013 into VS 2019 and it kept spitting errors that didn't even make sense.